# Source and destination attribute types are incompatible in SwiftData

Tags: swift, swift-data

When I migrate my schema from version to version with all migration's logic is set, the error still shows up even before the willMigrate closure's execution(I tried the debug). 
The migration I want to do is change my SubTask class's id from String to UUID. And the error occurs when I modify the `typealias SubTask = SubTaskSchemaV2.SubTask` from `typealias SubTask = SubTaskSchemaV1.SubTask` 
My Persistence container initializer:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

typealias Task = TaskSchemaV4.Task
typealias SubTask = SubTaskSchemaV2.SubTask


let PersistentDataTypes: [any PersistentModel.Type] = [Task.self, SubTask.self]

class PersistenceContainer {
    static let shared = PersistenceContainer().container

    private let container: ModelContainer

    init() {
        let fullSchema = Schema(PersistentDataTypes)
        let task: ModelConfiguration
        do {
            let appSupportConfig = try AppSupportConfig()
            task = ModelConfiguration(
                schema: fullSchema,
                url: URL(filePath: appSupportConfig.taskStoreFile!.path(percentEncoded: false))
            )
        } catch {
            fatalError("error generating config file under Application Support")
        }

        do {
            try container = ModelContainer(for: fullSchema, migrationPlan: MigrationPlan.self, configurations: task)
        } catch {
            fatalError("error creating ModelContainer")
        }
    }
}
```

My SubTask Version1:

```swift
enum SubTaskSchemaV1: VersionedSchema {
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 0, 0)
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [SubTask.self]
    }

    @Model
    final class SubTask {
        @Attribute(.unique, originalName: "id") var id: String
        @Attribute(originalName: "created_at") var createdAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "updated_at") var updatedAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "name") var name: String
        @Attribute(originalName: "task") var task: Task?

        init(id: String, createdAt: Date, updatedAt: Date, name: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.updatedAt = updatedAt
            self.name = name
        }
    }
}
```

My SubTask Version 2:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

enum SubTaskSchemaV2: VersionedSchema {
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 1, 0)
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [SubTask.self]
    }

    @Model
    final class SubTask {
        @Attribute(.unique, originalName: "id") var id: UUID
        @Attribute(originalName: "created_at") var createdAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "updated_at") var updatedAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "name") var name: String
        
        @Attribute(originalName: "task") var task: Task?

        init(id: UUID, createdAt: Date, updatedAt: Date, name: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.updatedAt = updatedAt
            self.name = name
        }

        convenience init(name: String) {
            self.init(id: UUID(), createdAt: Date.now, updatedAt: Date.now, name: name)
        }
    }
}
```

My Migration Plan:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

private var subTaskNumMigratedkBefore: Int = 0

struct SubTaskMigrationPlan: DataMigration {
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] {
        [migrationV1toV2]
    }

    static var schemas: [VersionedSchema.Type] {
        [SubTaskSchemaV1.self, SubTaskSchemaV2.self]
    }

    static let migrationV1toV2 = MigrationStage.custom(fromVersion: SubTaskSchemaV1.self, toVersion: SubTaskSchemaV2.self, willMigrate: { context in
        do {
            var subTasksV1 = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SubTaskSchemaV1.SubTask>())
            subTaskNumMigratedkBefore = subTasksV1.count
            subTasksV1.forEach { subTaskV1 in
                let subTaskV2 = SubTaskSchemaV2.SubTask(id: UUID(), createdAt: subTaskV1.createdAt, updatedAt: subTaskV1.updatedAt, name: subTaskV1.name)
                context.delete(subTaskV1)
                context.insert(subTaskV2)
            }
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("fetch SubTaskSchemaV1.SubTask failed, \(error)")
       }
        print("SubTaskV1toV2 willMigrate is done")
    }, didMigrate: { context in
        do {
            var subTasksV1 = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SubTaskSchemaV1.SubTask>())
            var subTasksV2 = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SubTaskSchemaV2.SubTask>())
            if subTasksV1.count != 0 {
                fatalError("data not cleaned up")
            }
            if subTasksV2.count != subTaskNumMigratedkBefore {
                fatalError("data consistence fail")
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
        print("SsubTaskV1toV2 didMigrate is done")
        
    })
}
```

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

protocol DataMigration {
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] { get }

    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] { get }
}

enum MigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] {
        TaskMigrationPlan.stages + SubTaskMigrationPlan.stages
    }

    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] {
        TaskMigrationPlan.schemas + SubTaskMigrationPlan.schemas
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
subtasks = \"(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x600001208500>), name subtasks, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Task, renamingIdentifier subtasks, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, destination entity SubTask, inverseRelationship task, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 2\";\n    updatedAt = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000d0b300>), name updatedAt, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Task, renamingIdentifier updated_at, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO, allowsCloudEncryption NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n        (\n        id\n    )\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, reason=Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002dbadf0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134190 "(null)" UserInfo={entity=SubTask, property=id, reason=Source and destination attribute types are incompatible}}}
```

By the way, My Task class's migrations are all lightweight, they works fine. Someone please help my.

Comment: The error seems related to the property `subtask` which I assume is a property on `Task` although it seems to complain about `SubTask`. Could it be so simple that you need to migrate `SubTask` before `Task`? I assume the order is determined by the `stages` array. Also, you are not setting the `task` property when migrating `SubTask` which looks like a bug.

Comment: You do not migrate task attribute.